# Calculate average for specific values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to calculate the average of a column but I'm getting stuck because, if a value is within a certain range than only I'd like to include that.

So if I had the following values:

```
100, 150, 500, 450, 300, 750
```

Now, I want to include only the values which is greater than 400 as a part of average.

then the query would calculate the average of these values:

```
500, 450, 750
```

and the output will be (500+450+750)/3

I tried

1)

```
select avg(case when value > 400 then value else 0 end) avg_val
from test
```

This is giving output as (0+0+500+450+0+750)/6. This is what not I wanted!

2)

```
select SUM(case when value > 400 then value else 0 end) /
           SUM(case when value > 400 then 1 else 0 end) avg_val
from test
```

this is throwing error saying `divide by zero` if there is no value greater than 400.

Can anybody help ? I am using PostgreSQL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, `AVG()` doesn't calculate null values, so you can use your query and replace 0 with `NULL`:

```
select avg(case when value > 400 then value else null end) avg_val
from test
```

Which can be formatted without the else part as well, since the default of the else is `NULL`

```
select avg(case when value > 400 then value end) avg_val
from test
```

Comment: @Rajeevkumar No problem :) I'll appreciate an approval then

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
select avg(value)
from test
where value > 400
```

Comment: But I think he want to select it with other values as well, just the average column should be only values greater then 400

Comment: @sagi, you may be right, but then OP needs to add other columns to the example data and result.

Comment: @Rajeevkumar This answer is the best for the question as it is. Make the question and samples as simple and as complete as possible to reflect the real problem.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products where price between 10 and 30;

SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM bidding where price >=2500 ;